# How to restrict Apache2 to listen from port 80?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have changed some files, but still the Apache2 listen from the 80 port.

```
Edited this line "Listen 44400" to the file ports.conf
Edited this "VirtualHost *:44400" to the file /site-enabled/000-default.conf
```

At this point of time, Apache2 is listening through ports 80 and 44400. I want Apache2 to listen from just 44400 port only.

 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have a second configuration file most likely called "listen.conf" which contains your port 80.

Comment: sir, there is no such file in /etc/apache2
Here is the list of the files: apache2.conf, envvars, magic, ports.conf.

Comment: Depending on the distribution (mine: OpenSuse 11/12/13), these files tend to be different.
Use:

    cd /etc/apache2/
    fgrep -R Listen\ 80 *

Should show you all files with Listen 80 in it.

Comment: mine is ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
please this image: http://postimg.org/image/mc2xjxzov/ Let me know, if I have done something wrong, p.s.: I am new to Linux

Comment: You did it correct. We will just have to cast a wider net:

Grep for port 80 only and see what shows up:
fgrep -R 80 *

Comment: sir, her e is the link to the results:
1. http://postimg.org/image/52qfzcyon/
2. http://postimg.org/image/o5bzobj4n/

Comment: Strange. No ports.conf file present either? Should have shown up.

Ok, last try for today (I do not have Ubuntu running, so guessing at some file names):
Add a file ports.conf with the line "Listen 80"
See if ports.conf is already included in your apache configuration by grepping for ports.conf (fgrep -R ports.conf *). If not, open apache2.conf and add the following line1:
"Include ports.conf" (without the quotes)

Comment: Sir, I have already changed ports.conf file from Listen 80 to Listen 44400 that is why, it is not showing up.

Comment: Apache only loads one config file initially.  In Ubuntu that's usually /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.  Inside that file (with the Ubuntu defaults) are instructions to Apache to load other config files:
 `# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` (and soforth)
So there's almost certainly something in one of those included files that tells it to listen on 80.  The grep command @norbert-van-nobelen suggested should find it, but you might also just look through all of the included files.

Comment: @ratsbane: sir I didn't get you, what exactly should I do ?

Comment: You might look through all of the conf files in `sites-enabled/` directory. That's often a place you'll find :80 configurations.

Comment: @ratsbane: sir in this folder, there is only 000-default.conf file, which already have been changed, please refer the question, I have already mentioned this.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That doesn't look like the list of files I would expect to see in /etc/apache2 in Ubuntu.  I think maybe your Apache configuration is including some files that aren't in the /etc/apache2 directory. What do you get when you do this: `grep -i include /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Also it's possible your Apache isn't using the config file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` at all.  If you start Apache with -f {filename} then it will use {filename} as the config file.  do `ps aux | grep apache` to see the startup command.  If it contains -f {filename} then take a closer look at {filename}

Comment: Ah, yes.  In addition to the sites-enabled directory you also have a conf-enabled directory.  What's in that?

Comment: sites-enabled consists of:
charset.conf
localized-error-pages.conf
security.conf
other-vhosts-access-log.conf
serve-cgi-bin.conf

Comment: Those files normally wouldn't contain a `listen` directive, though it is possible.

Comment: Just found out, something strange, used netstat -tulpn | grep :80
It outputs LISTEN - and same is the case for port 44400.
I think it should display the apache to atleast one of the port.

Comment: Hmm.  I get essentially the same output for netstat - PID/Program Name column is empty, even with the -l option.  Not sure what that means.